# AMP image going beyond DIV limits

Tags: amp-html, responsive-images

I'm trying to use AMP on my blog and converting images to AMP images results in images going out of DIVs and breaking up the whole display.

When AMP is not activated, images look like this:

```
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3654" src="https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main.jpg" alt="honor 8x test avis review photo taille main" width="2500" height="1875" srcset="https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main.jpg 2500w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-300x225.jpg 300w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-768x576.jpg 768w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-1024x768.jpg 1024w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-1400x1050.jpg 1400w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-900x675.jpg 900w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-700x525.jpg 700w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-500x375.jpg 500w" sizes="(max-width: 2500px) 100vw, 2500px" />
```

When AMP is activated, they look like this

```
<amp-img  class="alignleft size-full wp-image-3654" src="https://www.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main.jpg" alt="honor 8x test avis review photo taille main" width="2500" height="1875" srcset="https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main.jpg 2500w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-300x225.jpg 300w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-768x576.jpg 768w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-1024x768.jpg 1024w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-1400x1050.jpg 1400w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-900x675.jpg 900w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-700x525.jpg 700w, https://test.laurentwillen.be/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/10/honor-8x-test-avis-review-photo-taille-main-500x375.jpg 500w" sizes="(max-width: 2500px) 100vw, 2500px" / layout="responsive" /></amp-img>
```

I simply performed a preg_replace to replace img tags by amp-img.

Without AMP, images stay inside parent DIVs but with AMP activated, they go completely out of the DIV. If I try to put the parent DIV to 10% of the width to see what happens, I see that the parent DIVs takes 10% of the width but the image keeps its size as if it was using a CSS float property.

You can see what it looks like here:
https://test.laurentwillen.be/gadgets/honor-8x-test-avis-et-prix/
I can force the parent DIV to be smaller but it doesn't affect the pictures.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: There are a lot of errors found in your page (you might want to check your AMP validator). I've noticed that there is an extra "`/`" after `sizes` and before `layout`. Try removing it and fix the errors in the validator to help your 
AMP page work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have set the "sizes"-attribute to be "100vw" up to the browser-width of 4000px

```
sizes="(max-width: 4000px) 100vw, 4000px"
```

changing the size of the parent div doesn't do anything because the  inside of the  really is positioned absolute, so not affected by the width of the parent div.

i found this article helpful, maybe it's useful for you too:
https://alistapart.com/article/using-responsive-images-now

Comment: Hi Rosina, yes, that's exactly the point. I have experimented different values but the problem is that above 1000px, the parent div occupies 75% of the width so I would naturally use 75vw but it doesn't matches exactly the available space, there is a slight difference. I would basically like to stretch the images to 100% of the available width. If I remove sizes with the browser console it works but if I remove it from the code, AMP doesn't display the image at all.